Understanding mlflow visualization
I am new to mlflow and I am comparing two models: randomforest and catboost.
But I have a problem understanding the result got:
mlflow
Can anyone explain what happend and whether what I did was correct or not?
I tried experimenting with one model but I got a different visualization that is a single dot.
